# Two dimensional character array

Tags: c, arrays, character

In the output the last character is not printed.

```
Input: 3 3
       abcabcabc
Expected Output: a b c a b c a b c
Actual Output: a b c a b c a b
```

Where is c???

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i,j,k,n;
    char a[3][3],b[3][3];
    printf("enter size\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    printf("enter character \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
            printf("%c ",a[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always check the return value from `scanf`, e.g. `if (2 != scanf("%d %d",&n,&k)) { ... error handling ....}`

Answer (score 5):

This `scanf()` call:

```
 scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
```

leaves a newline char (`\n`) in the input buffer which is read by the subsequent where you read chars in loop. That's why it takes one less input.

You can add:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

after `scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);` to ignore it. But it's generally accepted that `scanf()` is not well-suited for such input reading. So, you might be better off using `fgets()` and then parse it.

Relevant: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i,j,k,n;
    char a[3][3],b[3][3];
    printf("enter size\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    printf("enter character \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
            printf("%c ",a[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Added fflush(stdin) to clear previous newline char (\n) in the input buffer by scanf.